# Best way to pass data between RxJS pipable operators?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to pass URL besides getting its response data in next pipable operator of RxJS. What do you think is the smartest way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Here is an example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-passing-data-to-next-operator-question

I tried some operators, but I couldn't find right one.
(Actually, I don't even know why passing function which returns observable to `mergeMap` results in getting data as parameter of function in next operator...)

```
from([
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(url => this.getData(url)),
    tap(posts => console.log(posts[0])), // I want to get url too here!!
  ).subscribe();
```

I expect to get url and its response data as pair in pipable operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can map the response to whatever you want:

```
from([
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
]).pipe(
    mergeMap(url => this.getData(url).pipe(
      map(response => ({ response, url })),
    )),
    tap(response => console.log(response)),
  ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Simple, thanks!! I'm sharing the [solution example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-passing-data-to-next-operator-solution) based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the signature of [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) `mergeMap(project: function: Observable, resultSelector: function: any, concurrent: number): Observable`, you can use the `resultSelector` argument:

```
from([
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
])
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(url => 
      this.getData(url),
      (outerValue, innerValue) => ({ url: outerValue, posts: innerValue })),
    tap(({ posts, url })=> {
      console.log(posts);
      console.log(url);
    })
  ).subscribe();
```

This will effectively map both `url` and the result of `this.getData(url)` to an object that can be used in `tap()`.

Here is your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bshpfp) modified to show this in action.

**NOTE:** result selectors are in the [process of being deprecated/removed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated). While this solution may currently work, it will no longer be viable in future version of RxJS (7.x). The answer provided by @martin is definitely more "future-proof".

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I take future-proof one though this one is still interesting, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer is the correct one for the given code sample.

However for a more complex and longer chain of operators, passing previous values along to subsequent operators can become a quite complex task. Especially while using more advanced operators such as the expand operator.

In those cases, I prefer using a closure to store those values:

```
const myStream$ = () => {
   const urls = [
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
  ];
  let dataUrl;
  return from(urls).pipe(
      mergeMap(url => {
         dataUrl = url;
         return this.getData(url)
      }),
    // ... assuming more operators are called here ... //
    tap(posts => console.log(posts[0], dataUrl))
  );
};

myStream$().subscribe();
```

But again, for a more simple chain of operators, adding values to a returned object is the way to go.